# numpy matrix multiplication row-wise

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multiplication

I have one matrix, like

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]])
```

and I want to get a new matrix, where each element is the matrix product of the row of a with itself:

```
np.array([
    np.dot(np.array([a[0]]).T, np.array([a[0]])),
    np.dot(np.array([a[1]]).T, np.array([a[1]])),
    np.dot(np.array([a[2]]).T, np.array([a[2]])),
    np.dot(np.array([a[3]]).T, np.array([a[3]])),
])
```

which will be a 4x4 matrix with each element a 3x3 matrix.
After this I can sum over the 0 axis to get a new 3x3 matrix.

Is there any more elegant way to implement this except using loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to keep the first axis aligned and perform outer product between the second one -

```
a[:,:,None]*a[:,None,:] # or a[...,None]*a[:,None]
```

With [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), translates to -

```
np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk',a,a)
```

Comment: If you see my deleted answer, I was halfway there! Next time I'll get it right, thanks for answering. :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yup, you were close! :)

Comment: Thanks very much!! I tried, this is just what I desired. Never imagine broadcasting can be done this way.

Comment: I clicked on the check sign, is this OK? BTW: if I have another 1d array of length 4, how to multiply this 1d array with the above resulting array?

Comment: I got it. AA * b[:, None, None] will do it. @Divakar

Comment: @Divakar Hi, sorry to ask you again. Do you know how to apply cross product row wise? Like if I have a matrix, shape of (12, 12, 3), each element of the matrix is a vector, and I have another array composed of two vectors, so with shape (2, 3). I want to get the cross product of these two, elementwise, so I can get a new array of vectors, shape (2, 12, 12, 3), each (12, 12, 3) matrix corresponding to one of the two vectors.

Comment: @JQK `B[:,None,None,:] * A`, where A and B are the first and second arrays respectively?

Comment: @Divakar Thank you for your reply. Sorry, I did not make my query clear. What I want is cross product between the vectors, so multiplication directly does not seem to work well. Levi-Cevita symbol might be used, but I am not good at making clear einsum. I wonder if np.cross() could finish this. Thanks for your discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but isn't this just matrix multiplication ?

```
>>> a.T @ a
array([[30, 40, 50],
       [40, 54, 68],
       [50, 68, 86]])

>>> np.sum(np.array([
      np.dot(np.array([a[0]]).T, np.array([a[0]])),
      np.dot(np.array([a[1]]).T, np.array([a[1]])),
      np.dot(np.array([a[2]]).T, np.array([a[2]])),
      np.dot(np.array([a[3]]).T, np.array([a[3]])),
    ]), axis=0)
array([[30, 40, 50],
       [40, 54, 68],
       [50, 68, 86]])
```

Comment: Hi percusse, thanks for your comment, but no, they are not the same. I am calculating something like [1, 2, 3].T * [1, 2, 3] = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]], but what you are calculating is [1, 2, 3] * [1, 2, 3].T = [14].

Comment: @JQK I just copied your code and compared the result.

Comment: Yes, you seems to be correct, but I do not have time to check it yet.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I remember. When I was doing it yesterday, I need to multiply the matrix by some weight and then do the summation. The weight can be moved into the original array and then use the matrix multiplication method. Anyway, thanks for your help.